# Raspberry Pi 3B Windows 10 IOT UDP VB.NET

Tags: windows-iot

I am trying to send a UDP packet from my Pi3 running Windows 10 IOT.  I have found the c# code but I am running VB.NET.   I have had success in converting it except for one line item:

Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () >= {})

I have no idea how to convert this. I have no idea what () >= {} means.

Can someone explain it or at least give me an example of sending and receiving UDP in windows IOT using VB.net?  ALL the examples I find are in c#.

Comment: Well, lets see, I said all the examples I find are in c#.  What is up with so many people just saying "Have you googled it"?  Why don't people just help instead of being condescending?

Comment: i am not being condescending .... a lot of people post questions here without actually checking the internet first  ..... before i posted my comment, i googled `UDP in windows IOT using VB.net` and got this https://technotif.com/creating-simple-udp-server-client-transfer-data-using-c-vb-net/ ............ you must have found it also .... which part did not work for you?

Comment: Okay, yes, I can do it all day long in a regular VB.NET app, but the UWP does not support the way a normal desktop app does. The UWP from what I understand it uses the DatagramSocket, of which I can only find c# examples.

Comment: go to this page ... https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync  ..... select `VB` language at top right of screen .......... top snippet becomes VB .... compare with c# snippets below ...... `() >= {}` is the callback .... the callback code is in the curly braces.... next time please include the whole snippet in your question

Comment: Only: Public Function RunAsync(priority As CoreDispatcherPriority, agileCallback As DispatchedHandler) As IAsyncAction turns to vb code, the rest stays c# in my browser.

Comment: that is correct, but it provides a comparison between C# and VB ..... in the C# example, the callback code is inside the braces `{ }` ..... in C# you would have a separate `sub` for the callback code ... `agileCallback As DispatchedHandler`

Comment: I believe the right place to discuss C# syntax is StackOverflow.